# MarkLogic TDE on XML documents with XSD and XSI

Tags: xml, namespaces, marklogic, xsi

Hello i am using MarkLogic 9.0 and have a beginner level of experience with ML and XML. I have followed the [MarkLogic SQL Guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql) successfully and want to use it in the real world and extract from transactional xml files the the type element. But in the view which i created returns an empty result. I think it has something to do with the xsd and the xsi. But as I mentioned earlier I am at a beginner level and I don't know how to fix this.

The following text describe the scenario to reproduce the problem.

I load 3500 xml documents to the SQLData(with triple store index) I also created a SQLSchema database which is related tot the SQLData database as described in the Guide. All XML documents has a similar structure like the example below:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <item>
    <transaction>
      <type>CI</type>
      <sscc>00000379461100000007</sscc>
      <location>4260210630688</location>
      <device>VISTALINK.004</device>
      <date>2017-04-25</date>
      <time>01:22:20</time>
      <gmtOffset>+02:00</gmtOffset>
      <actorId>155081</actorId>
    </transaction>
    <order>
      <orderNumber>3794611</orderNumber>
    </order>
  </item>
</scope>
```

with a URI like this(all documents has a similar structure):

```
/transactions/2017-04-25_01-22-20_3794611_00000379461100000007_CI.xml
```

Now i created a template with the following structure:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" 
        at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $transactions :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/transactions</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>main</schema-name>
      <view-name>transactions</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>type</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>type</val>
        </column>
    </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>
return tde:template-insert("Transactions.xml", $transactions)
```

I also to change the context to:

```
<context>item</context>
```

and
    /item

It does not return any error so i think the result will be fine

When I execute the following statement in the SQL console it returns an empty result:

```
select * from transactions;
```

When I validate the above template it returns the folowing result:

```
<map:map xmlns:map="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<map:entry key="valid">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:boolean">false</map:value>
</map:entry>
<map:entry key="error">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:string">TDE-INVALIDTEMPLATENODE</map:value>
</map:entry>
<map:entry key="message">
<map:value xsi:type="xs:string">TDE-INVALIDTEMPLATENODE: Invalid extraction template node: /tde:template/tde:rows/text()</map:value>
</map:entry>
</map:map>
```

So the error by validating is :

```
Invalid extraction template node: /tde:template/tde:rows/text()
Invalid extraction template node:
```

/tde:template/tde:rows/text()

Does any one know how I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe it is just a simple mistake. You have `<context>/transactions</context>`, but context is like an XSLT match expression, not a directory filter. You probably want to change the value to `transaction` or `item`, since there is no element with the name `transactions`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I try to change the value of the context element to item or transaction both get the same result (see adjust question).

Comment: I adjust now some aditional information about the validating results

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in your context. You have specified `<context>item</context>` but based on your sample document `item` is a child of `scope`. Therefore your template should look like this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace tde = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde" at "/MarkLogic/tde.xqy";

let $transactions :=
<template xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/tde">
  <context>/scope/item/transaction</context>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <schema-name>main</schema-name>
      <view-name>transactions</view-name>
      <columns>
        <column>
          <name>type</name>
          <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
          <val>type</val>
        </column>
    </columns>
    </row>
  </rows>
</template>
return tde:template-insert("Transactions.xml", $transactions)
```

So what are we doing here? We are specifying the context to be `/scope/item/transaction` because the column `type` that you've specified in your row definition is under these elements. Loading this template will allow you to run the SQL statement `SELECT * FROM transactions;`

Comment: You can leave off `/scope/item/` from the context. It accepts ["Any indexable path expression"](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_71415), but should indeed be `transaction` rather than `item`, otherwise the expression for the `type` column won't return anything, and TDE will complain: `Eval for Column type='type' returns an empty sequence for a non-nullable column`..

Comment: No worries at all :)